# Connecting Arduino with GPS receiver

Tags: arduino-due, gps

I have the components as shown and I installed the TinyGPS library. [image: GPS module, Arduino, connecting wires]

I'm pretty new to hardware stuff and I'm not sure if these wires would work? (pins on both sides)

The GPS module has 5 pins - GND,5V,IN,OUT and I can barely read the last one. I'm assuming I need to connect only the first 4?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: looks like you really need wires with male and female ends.....

Comment: @ChadG: So I thought. Is there any workaround, like using a breadboard to interface?

Comment: yes... if you put the gps in a breadboard, then the male/male jumpers would be fine.....

Comment: `I'm assuming I need to connect only the first 4` ... never assume anything .... please post a closeup of the GPS module, back and front, with the writing oriented upright (i'm too lazy to turn my laptop sideways. lol)

Comment: @jsotola: I figured this out, thanks nonetheless :)